# default selected for ng-options in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code:

```
<select ng-init="state" id="state" ng-model="state"
    ng-options="state for state in states" required>
</select>
```

So, for default selected, it will choose whatever `$scope.state` is in the controller. This is working fine. But sometimes, `$scope.state` will be empty. When this is the case, I want the default selected value to be 'Select a state'. So, I tried the following:

```
<select ng-init="state || 'Selected a state'" id="state" ng-model="state"
    ng-options="state for state in states" required>
</select>
```

This did not work.

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another *default* option inline like this:

```
<select ng-init="state" id="state" ng-model="state" ng-options="state for state in states" required>
    <option value="">Select a state</option>
</select>
```

And this *null* option will be selected as the default.